# Android WebView not loading below Android 8 from cache folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I am loading html files from cache directory of app into Android WebView. Files are loaded and displayed in WebView in android 8 and above. But when I tested on android 7 and below, these files are not loaded, WebView does not show anything. Here is the code snippet that I am using:

```
WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
String path = getCacheDir().getPath() + "/" + "file.html";
webView.loadUrl(path);
```

Comment: webView.loadUrl("file://" + path); ?

Comment: Great! It is working. You rock!